# How can ı define a char taking from digit of a number in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, digits, charat

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num = s.next();

        char a = num.charAt(0);
        char b = num.charAt(1);
        char c = num.charAt(2);
        char d = num.charAt(3);
```

For example , we can do it like this but i will enter long values ​​for input so how can i write it like loop or easier rather than write 20 line as ı wrote ?

I thought , i can write it using "for" but i couldn't.I am new to java so if you can solve it using basic methods or codes and explain so , i would  be grateful.

```
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    String num = inp.next();

    char a = num.charAt(0);
    char b = num.charAt(1);
    char c = num.charAt(2);
    char d = num.charAt(3);
    char e = num.charAt(4);
    char f = num.charAt(5);
    char g = num.charAt(6);
    char h = num.charAt(7);

    if (a < '2') {
        System.out.print("0" + "" + b + "" + c + "" + d + "" + e + "" + f + "" + g + "" + h);
    } else if (a > '2' & h == '0') {
        System.out.print("0" + "" + b + "" + c + "" + d + "" + e + "" + f + "" + g + "" + "1");
    } else if (a > '2' && h == '1') {
        System.out.print("0" + "" + b + "" + c + "" + d + "" + e + "" + f + "" + g + "" + "0");
    }
```

As well,Im trying for easier way of that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your attempt with the `for` loop, it would be a reasonable approach for this. However, I don't quite understand what you're attempting to do with this data ("a char taking from digit of a number" isn't very clear).

Comment: My bad , its part of my hw actually.There are some inputs and ı need to write "clean" version that if first digit isnot 0 or 1 , the last digit must be changed.If its 0 ,it will be 1 or if its 1,it will be 0.If first digit is 0 or 1,nothing will be change.For that reasons,i thought , i have to define each digit to char.Actually i did it but its just for the one 2-digit numbers ı need to do for 6 2-digit numbers.Have a look.

Comment: You can simply use `String#charAt` to evalulate those directly, no need for a variable.

Comment: What do you think about the code ı wrote ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with variables named `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.  You could only do it with an array, where you could index them by number, e.g. `char[] chars`, and use `chars[0]` instead of `a`, `chars[25]` instead of `z`, and so on.

To do that, you can just do `char[] chars = num.toCharArray()`, or even skip the array entirely and keep using `charAt`.